# Recommendations on libraries for building Clojure web apps

Tags: web-applications, clojure

It's late 2012 and I can't find *recent* recommendations on a set of libraries for building "traditional" web apps with Clojure.

I've liked [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) and [Korma](http://sqlkorma.com/), and ClojureWekz Mailer seems nice, are there any other suggestions?

I'm looking for specific advice on libraries for:

- Templates
- Mailers
- Testing
- Web assets

Thanks!

Edit: Changed "framework" to "libraries" as suggested, since I'm not looking for a whole stack, but a set of recommended libraries for common tasks and features (listed above)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a `single framework` kind of thing in Clojure world. You basically have different libraries which solve a specific problem like `Noir` is for there to specify request handlers, `enlive` for server side templates and so on. So basically you choose libraries for different purpose of your application and then build you app, which for me is more preferable approach than those big heavy frameworks like you have in .NET/Java world.

Although this may pose a problem for someone new to clojure to get started as he/she will probably be looking to something like a framework which can quickly churn out a simple app but in long term this library approach is more beneficial then big chunky frameworks.

One important aspect of this library approach is that these libraries should be composable to make this non-framework approach work and this is achieved by using the clojure inbuilt data structures such as vector, sets, maps etc and expose functionality using simple composable functions.

Answer (score 0):

there are bunch of library listed on [clojure-toolbox](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/) for different purpose you can go there and check.

Note: these site is not getting updated from couple of months so most recent libraries is not available [here](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/)